# NoClassDefFoundError Bigquery

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, noclassdeffounderror, google-bigquery

I am adding Bigquery to an app engine Java servlet (sampleServelt) that runs in a background queue.

The servlet compiles, but at run time,I get the following.

```
2014-03-02 15:01:36.260

Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/services/bigquery/Bigquery
at com.example.lifescore.SampleServlet.<clinit>(SampleServlet.java:102)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:370)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:446)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery
at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-cbfbce12c9fde159(Request.java)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:360)
at com.example.lifescore.SampleServlet.<clinit>(SampleServlet.java:102)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:370)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
... 1 more
```

My app engine server has bigQuery enabled, with billing, and with the correct rights for myself (edit rights).

The error points to my java line 102 which is following bigquery definition line to instantiate a bigquery service.  This code is copied from https://developers.google.com/bigquery/authorization#service-accounts-appengine.

```
public class SampleServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final String SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery";
    private static final HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new UrlFetchTransport();
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

    // @VisibleForTesting
    static Bigquery bigquery = new Bigquery(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getRequestInitializer());

    private static String getProjectId() {
        // In App Engine each app has a BigQuery project id with the same name as the app.
        // You'll need to turn on the BigQuery API on the cloud console for this to work.
        return AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService().getServiceAccountName().split("@")[0];
    }

    private static HttpRequestInitializer getRequestInitializer() {
        if (System.getProperty("OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN") != null) {
            // Good for testing and localhost environments, where no AppIdentity is available.
            return new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(System.getenv("OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN"));
        }
        return new AppIdentityCredential(Arrays.asList(new String[] {SCOPE}));
    }
```

I am wondering if this is authorization failure, or if it really is that bigquery is not found by the JVM, or possibly the failure is not finding one of the libraries on the line 102 for TRANSPORT,JSON_FACTORY,or getRequestInitializer().

Comment: The comment from Andrei was spot on.  I am using vanilla Eclipse and was sloppy in have jars spread around various directorys.  When I made sure that all jars were inside the WAR/WEB-INF/LIB, then the error was removed.   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check that you included the required library in the WEB-INF/lib folder.

In Eclipse, you may see a warning in the Problems tab, which says that a particular file will not be available on a server classpath. You need to add this file to this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check the jar files are added to your lib or not.